# Name becomes null after refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a [website](http://jessecsmagazine.coolpage.biz) that doesn't really work the way I want it to. If you enter a name and comment, it will properly write it below the comment section. But when you refresh, the name becomes null.

Github:
https://github.com/thebestbestman123/my_magazine

Comment: so what do you want to do?

Comment: I want it to keep the name, not change it to null. But I still looked through the database and it still has all the names. Maybe it's because of my database requests. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your table row title was "name" not "commenter"
https://github.com/thebestbestman123/my_magazine/blob/master/php/get_comments.php

```
$rowarray["name"] = $row["commenter"];
```

Based from your saving row name:
https://github.com/thebestbestman123/my_magazine/blob/master/php/add_comment.php

> sprintf("INSERT INTO comments (id, **name**, comment, timestamp)
>   VALUES (null, '%s', '%s', null)"

Comment: You were right! I accidentally forgot to change that when I got the code from a different source!